# Why VBS wont work in my IE at all?

Tags: html, vbscript

I am trying to make a html with vbs. but it wont work at all. I am sure running script is enabled in my IE10. IE9. I also tried in chrome and firefox, non of them works....

I m just wondering that if there are some issue with my code or issues with IE. I know IE 11 wont support vbs anymore, but we still on IE 10. so any suggestion?

This is just a simple test page, but it wont work.....

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Validation in Button Event</title>

<script language="VBScript">
<!--

Sub Button1_OnClick
    Dim TheForm
    Set TheForm = Document.forms("ValidForm")
    If IsNumeric(TheForm.Text1.Value) Then
        If TheForm.Text1.Value < 1 Or TheForm.Text1.Value > 10 Then
            MsgBox "Please enter a number between 1 and 10."
        Else
            MsgBox "Thank you."
            TheForm.Submit
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter a numeric value."
    End If

End Sub
-->
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h3>Validation in Button Event</h3>
<hr>

<form id="ValidForm">

Enter a value between 1 and 10: 
<input name="Text1" type="text" size="2">
<input name="Button1" type="button" value="Click Here">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is a very bad idea, especially as you know it won't be supported for long, you're just wasting your time !

Comment: Use javascript. You are not doing anything special that javascript cannot do.

Comment: Pretty sure no browser besides IE has ever supported VBS.

Comment: It works here. VBS is popular in asp pages and intranets.

Comment: what ie version you on? I tried ie 8-10, non of em works...

Answer (score 0):

Well in this example the VBScript is commented out

VBScript still works fine (always has) in Firefox (I am currently using version 32.0.3)